# El parametro tiene implícitamente un tipo 'any'

Tags: html, typescript, aplicación-web, angular-cli

Estoy trabajando con Angular y me encuentro con un error en los parámetros, en la terminal me dice: "Parameter 'email' implicitly has an 'any' type", la verdad no se porque me aparece, ojala me puedan ayudar.

**TypeScript**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-first',
  templateUrl: './form-first.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-first.component.css']
})
export class FormFirstComponent implements OnInit {

  status ="Form not submitted"
  defaultName = ""

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSendForm(email){//Lógica que quiero que haga 
    console.log(email) 
    this.status ="Form has been sent"
  }

  onDefaultForm(){
    this.defaultName = "Alberto"
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
  <p>form-first works!</p>
<p>Name</p>
<input type="text" name="" [value]="defaultName">
<p>Email</p>
<input #email type="text" name="">
<hr>
<button (click)="onSendForm(email)">Send Form</button> <!-- Método que se genera y se aplica en el component--> 
<hr>
<button (click)="onDefaultForm()">Default Form</button>
<p>{{ status }}</p>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estimado, acompaña la imagen con el código para que tu respuesta sea bien recibida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tienes que especificar el tipo de objeto que va a recibir la función, si no tienes claro el tipado que estas recibiendo lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
   onSendForm(email: any){ // de esta manera no te saltará un error y funcionará
    console.log(email) 
    this.status ="Form has been sent"
  }
```

Como recomendación si sabes que el valor email es de tipo string establécelo y de esa forma te quedará el código mucho más accesible y limpio.

Ejemplo de como sería si la información que te llega es de tipo string:

```
   onSendForm(email: string){ // de esta manera definimos que lo que nos llega es de tipo string
    console.log(email) 
    this.status ="Form has been sent"
  }
```

Esto es aplicable a cualquier tipado que vayas a usar o incluso modelos.

Espero haberte ayudado y cualquier pregunta no dudes en hacerla!